# Mysql how to increase serial number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stored procedure in MySql which user will pass in a number e.g. 'cr002149'
Now I want to increase the number by 1 for each record in select statment. How can I do that to let the number become e.g. cr002150,cr002151...

Thanks.

Comment: will cr remain always the same

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

You should reconsider your data structure, you might get better luck just using an `auto_increment`'d integer. Either way, this should do.

```sql
CONCAT('cr',
  LPAD(
    CAST(
      SUBSTRING('cr002149',3) AS DECIMAL(0)
    )+1,
    6,'0'
  )
);
```

The above will return `cr002150`. First, we get `002149` using `SUBSTRING`, then cast the string `002149` to an integer and get `2149`. Now, we increment this to get `2150`, followed by left-padding it by 0s to get `002150`, and finally we concatenate `cr` on the left side.